# Solrnet Extract not working (java.lang.IllegalStateException)

Tags: tomcat, extract, solrnet, apache-tika

I'm facing a problem with Solrnet, every time i try to use the solr.extract method to retrieve the content text of PDF/word... files i get the following error :

13-Oct-2014 12:15:12.340 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-35] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet default a généré une exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Unknown Source)

here's my code :

```
            var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<SOLR_DocumentPJ>>();
            using (var file = File.OpenRead(@"c:\test.pdf"))
            {
                var response = solr.Extract(new
                ExtractParameters(file, "abcd1")
                                {
                                    StreamType="application/pdf",
                                    ExtractOnly = true,
                                    ExtractFormat = ExtractFormat.Text,
                                });

                filecontent = response.Content;
            }
```

thank you for any help.

---

Just one more thing : we use SOLR 4.10.0 in a windows machine, not a linux one, maybe we missed something to configure tika correctly?

Comment: There should be more useful bits above that in the error log, anything there saying why it didn't start?

Comment: Ok, sorry here's the complete error log if it can help :   http://shorttext.com/5d90d5d6

Comment: Still doesn't look complete...

Comment: Agreed, but that's all i have in the tomcat 8.0/log directory, it seems that the last bits are truncated (...32 more) I looked everywere else and couldn't find anymore log

Comment: Ok, here's the stack from VisualStudio, seems more complete after all : http://shorttext.com/5d93b5b1

Comment: Up please, i'm still having the same problem and no clue...furtermore it seems to appears randomly